# $\mathcal{L} \int_{[A,B)} fd\lambda = \lim_{b \to B} \mathcal{R} \int_A^b f(x)dx.$

Tags: lebesgue-integral

Let $ -\infty < A < B \leq +\infty$, and let $f:[A,B)\to \mathbb{R}$ be almost continuous everywhere (sucht that $f_{[A,b]} \in \mathcal{R}(A,b)$ for all $A<b<B$). Then $\mathcal{R} \int_A^B f(x)dx := \lim_{b \to B} \mathcal{R} \int_A^b f(x)dx.$

---

The following is a condition when the improper Riemann integral is the same as the Lebesgue integral. How do I prove this?

If $g \geq 0$ with $g \in \mathcal{L}([A,B))$ and $|f| \leq g$, then

$$\mathcal{L} \int_{[A,B)} fd\lambda = \lim_{b \to B} \mathcal{R} \int_A^b f(x)dx.$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $ f $ is almost-everywhere continuous then $ \mathcal{R} \int_A^b{f(x) dx} = \mathcal{L} \int_A^b{f(x) dx} $ for all $ A < b < B $.  So the only thing you have to prove is
$$
(*)\quad \lim_{b \rightarrow B} {\mathcal{L}\int_A^b{f(x) dx}} = \mathcal{L}\int_A^B{f(x) dx}
$$

For this, note $ \mathcal{L}\int_A^b{f(x) dx} = \mathcal{L} \int_A^B{f(x) \chi_{[A,b)} dx} $.  Now letting $ b_n $ be any sequence $ b_n \rightarrow B $, and $ f_n(x) = f(x)\chi_{[A,b_n)} $, we have $ |f_n(x)| < g(x) $ and $ f_n(x) \rightarrow f(x) $ (almost everywhere) on $ [A,B] $.  The dominated convergence theorem immediately gives us the desired limit $ (*) $.